# addition operation to a field generated by $addfied

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want add +1 to the generated field "diff_days" and take the value left side of the point.

my query is:

```
db.Jobs.aggregate([
{ "$addFields": {
  "timeDifference": {  "$subtract": [  "$jobEndDateMilliSeconds",Date.now() ]},
}},
{ "$addFields": { "diff_days": {
          "$divide": [
              "$timeDifference",
              1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
              ]
          } 
          },  
          },
{"$match":{ jobEndDateMilliSeconds: { $gte: Date.now() }}},
{"$sort":{"timeDifference":1}},
{"$limit":1}
])
```

OUTPUT:

```
"jobProfile" : "Java Developer",
"jobID" : "1",
"jobCountry" : "India",
"openingsCount" : 10,
"jobType" : "Fulltime",
"jobDescription" : "profile description",
"postingDate" : "07-08-2018 04:21:22",
"jobStatus" : "Active",
"jobEndDate" : ISODate("2018-08-14T23:59:59.999Z"),
"jobEndDateMilliSeconds" : 1534204859999.0,
"timeDifference" : 216862093.0,
"diff_days" : 3
```

please help me.Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$add](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/add/index.html) with two arguments: first one is your evaluated value and second will be `1` as const value and then [$trunc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/trunc/index.html) to truncate to integer:

```
db.Jobs.aggregate([
    { "$addFields": {
      "timeDifference": {  "$subtract": [  "$jobEndDateMilliSeconds",Date.now() ]},
    }},
    { "$addFields": { "diff_days": {
        $trunc: { $add: [
        {
              "$divide": [
                  "$timeDifference",
                  1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
                  ]
        }, 1
    ] }
    }
              },  
              },
    {"$match":{ jobEndDateMilliSeconds: { $gte: Date.now() }}},
    {"$sort":{"timeDifference":1}},
    {"$limit":1}
])
```